# Add arrayList value one by one in SQLite database android when clicking button

Tags: android, android-sqlite

```
roomNames = new ArrayList<>();

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, roomNames);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
            roomSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

if (item.getGroupId() == 0) {
  /////please  any one can help me how to save roomNames value in database 

} 
Thank you
```

Comment: please read these: [page1](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) [page2](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) [page3](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

insert all data into data base

```
public void insert_data() {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    for (int i = 0; i < roomNames.size(); i++) {

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(KEY_DATE, roomNames.get(i));

        // insert row
        db.insert(TABLE_DATA, null, values);
    }
    if (db != null) {
        db.close();
    }
}
```